# Boot to command line 12.04 (grub options not working)

Tags: 12.04, grub2, headless

I installed 12.04 Desktop because I want the option to run Unity in the future, but I PREFER to work headless via SSH.

I changed the following in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

changed to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

Rebooted and still get the graphical Unity interface

changed the above to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

Rebooted and again, no love -- still get the Unity interface.

I see that `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is generated automagically by grub-mkconfig using templates `/etc/grub.d` and `/etc/default`.

I saw that my first option in grub still read thusly:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-27-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c40e42d6-6e01-4abf-b2e3-e46132dcfa0a    linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic root=UUID=3a07789f-f0b4-4123-a26a-6f245ef9054e ro   quiet splash $vt_handoffeneric
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-27-generic ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic root=UUID=3a07789f-f0b4-4123-a26a-6f245ef9054e ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.5.0-27-generic
 }
```

Note that it still reads 'quiet splash' above (single quotes mine).  So I ran grub-mkconfig to see if that was needed to re-build grub.cfg from /etc/default/grub, but even after running that, 'quiet splash' persists.

Can anyone advise on where I'm going wrong?  I just want my bash...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash text"`

then update grub:

`sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Yep, Stef, the key part that I neglected is really embarrassing, as  I usually RTFM and it clearly states in /etc/default/grub, "Run update-grub after making any changes"

So, your answer is great and "noquiet nosplash text" is just what I wanted.   And to future users, RUN sudo update-grub !!!!!